# 5000 item threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a doc library with 6000 items in it. Despite 4 main cols being indexed, the filters will not sort all items, eg A-Z.

If I try to do this the library throws an error.

Yet I have seen on an Ignite demo (posted on 28 Sep 2017) that the library should be able to sort items between 5000 and 20000 docs once col indexing is enabled. So my filters should work.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwY8UYrTNiU&feature=youtu.be (around 20 mins in)

Any ideas? Thanks Vicki

Comment: Is the filter set on non-indexed columns?

Comment: Is it on a 'modern' site? On Prem or O365?

Comment: This is a modern doc library, sharepoint online. I am using an all docs view sorted by modified date which loads ok but fails when I then try to filter A-Z on any of my 4 indexed columns.